# How many goals has Steven Gerrard scored?

Tags: code-golf

[Steven Gerrard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steven_Gerrard) was born on 30th of May 1980. He is now 37 years old. Happy birthday, Steven!

To celebrate his anniversary, your goal is to remind him the number of goals he has scored each year in premiere league for Liverpool.

He doesn't want to remember the goals scored before or after playing for Liverpool. It is like scoring `0` goals.

**Input**

The starting year of football season.

**Output**

The number of goals scored by Steven during this season for Liverpool.

**List of seasons and goals**

```
1998–99     0
1999–2000   1   
2000–01     7   
2001–02     3   
2002–03     5   
2003–04     4   
2004–05     7   
2005–06     10  
2006–07     7   
2007–08     11  
2008–09     16  
2009–10     9   
2010–11     4   
2011–12     5   
2012–13     9   
2013–14     13  
2014–15     9
```

**Example**

```
Input    Output
2002     5
2017     0
1990     0
2014     9
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest submission in bytes in each language wins. Explanations are encouraged.

Comment: Do we have to return 0 if the date is out of the range or can we throw an exception?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Steven Gerrard prefers to say that he has scored `0` goals. No exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>25</s> 24 bytes

```
•3ßÎó‚4Ëǝï•17в15ÝƵÊØ+Ikè
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATgAx/8wNWFiMWX//@KAojPDn8OOw7PigJo0w4vHncOv4oCiMTfQsjE1w53GtcOKw5grSWvDqP//MjAwMA)
or as a [Test suite](https://tio.run/##AUsAtP8wNWFiMWX/MTk5MCAyMDIwxbh2ef/igKIzw5/DjsOz4oCaNMOLx53Dr@KAojE30LIxNcOdxrXDisOYK3lrw6j/eSLDvzogw78iLP8)

**Explanation**

```
•3ßÎó‚4Ëǝï•                 # push the number 69255401071877657848
           17в              # convert to list of base-17 digits
                            # produces the list [1,7,3,5,4,7,10,7,11,16,9,4,5,9,13,9,0]

              15Ý           # push the range [0 ... 15]
                 ƵÊØ+       # add the 303rd prime (1999) to each
                     Ik     # get the index of the input in this list
                            # or -1 if outside the range
                       è    # get the element at that index in first list
```

Answer (score 21):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>47</s> <s>43</s> <s>42</s> 39 bytes

```js
y=>+'0723135148933694'[y-1999]+y%20%9|0
```

#### How?

We compute an approximation ***x*** of the number of goals for a given year ***y*** with the formula:

```js
x = y % 20 % 9
```

This is actually a very bad approximation, but it's always less than or equal to the expected value ***v*** and never less than ***v - 9***, which allows to encode the difference with a single decimal digit.

```
y    | y % 20 | x = y % 20 % 9 | v  | v - x
-----+--------+----------------+----+------
1999 |     19 |              1 |  1 |     0
2000 |      0 |              0 |  7 |     7
2001 |      1 |              1 |  3 |     2
2002 |      2 |              2 |  5 |     3
2003 |      3 |              3 |  4 |     1
2004 |      4 |              4 |  7 |     3
2005 |      5 |              5 | 10 |     5
2006 |      6 |              6 |  7 |     1
2007 |      7 |              7 | 11 |     4
2008 |      8 |              8 | 16 |     8
2009 |      9 |              0 |  9 |     9
2010 |     10 |              1 |  4 |     3
2011 |     11 |              2 |  5 |     3
2012 |     12 |              3 |  9 |     6
2013 |     13 |              4 | 13 |     9
2014 |     14 |              5 |  9 |     4
```

#### Demo

```js
let f =

y=>+'0723135148933694'[y-1999]+y%20%9|0

for(y = 1997; y <= 2017; y++) {
  console.log(y, f(y))
}
```

Comment: Very nicely done.

Comment: Wait. You're _computing_ the number of goals from the input year, instead of indexing in a hard-coded database?

Comment: @Blacksilver I need a first approximation to lower the range of stored values from _1-16_ to _0-9_. But there's still a hard-coded lookup table to store the differences with these computed values.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, 44 Bytes

```
y=>parseInt("173547a7bg9459d9"[y-1999],17)|0
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG. Nice first answer :)

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 44 Bytes

```php
<?=intval(_173547a7bg9459d9[$argn-1998],17);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#s7EvyCjgUkksSs@zNTIwsLDmsrf7b2Nvm5lXUpaYoxFvaG5samKeaJ6UbmliapliGQ1WqmtoaWkRq2Normn9/z8A)

Answer (score 1):

## PowerShell, 65 Bytes

```
(($g=(1,7,3,5,4,7,10,7,11,16,9,4,5,9,13,9)["$args"-1999]),0)[!$g]
```

uses a ternary/array format to return 0 if the year isn't in the array.

This is so long because powershell doesn't have any `else return 0` format, and the full array is required, if he scored 9 or less goals in each year we could shave a lot off this by indexing into a string instead.

Answer (score 1):

## Bash, <s>97</s> 93 Bytes

```
a=(1 7 3 5 4 7 10 7 11 16 9 4 5 9 13 9)
((2014<$1||$1<1999))&&(echo 0)||(echo $[a[$1-1999]])
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>50</s> 41 bytes

```
y=>+`0x${"06243696af8348c8"[y-1999]}`+1|0
```

---

### Try it

```js
f=
y=>+`0x${"06243696af8348c8"[y-1999]}`+1|0
oninput=_=>o.innerText=f(+i.value)
o.innerText=f(i.value=1998)
```

```html
<input id=i type=number><p id=o>
```

Answer (score 0):

## C#, <s>79</s> 72 bytes

```c#
y=>new[]{0,1,7,3,5,4,7,10,7,11,16,9,4,5,9,13,9}[y>2014|y<1999?0:y-1998];
```

Answer (score 0):

## Braingolf v0.6, 48 bytes

```
#ߎ-V173547#
792+82*945994+9&,0R!?1-[v>R]v_:0_|;
```

This is a weird one.

The character `ߎ` has the ordinal 1998, making `#ߎ` the Braingolf literal for 1998, which is then subtracted from the input.

#### Explanation:

```
#ߎ-V173547#
792+82*945994+9&,0R!?1-[v>R]v_:0_|;  Implicit input of n
#ߎ-                                  Subtract 1998 from n
   V                                 Create a new stack and switch to it
    173547                           Digit literals 1, 7, 3, 5, 4 and 7
          #<newline>                 Integer literal 10
792                                  Digit literals 7, 9 and 2
   +                                 Sum the last 2 items (9 and 2) to make 11
    82*                              Digit literals 8 and 2 multiplied to make 16
       9459                          Digit literals 9, 4, 5 and 9
           94+                       Digit literals 9 and 4 summed to make 13
              9                      Digit literal 9
               &,                    Reverse stack
                 0                   Digit literal 0
                  R                  Return to main stack
                   !?                If n != 0
                     1-              Decrement n
                       [...]         Loop, repeat n+1 times
                        v>           Move to next stack and rotate to the right
                          R          Return to main stack
                            v_       Move to next stack and output last item
                              :      Else
                               0_    Push zero and output
                                 |   Endif
                                  ;  Suppress implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>59</s> 58 bytes

Inspired by [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/123496/66418).

```python
lambda x:1997<x<2015and int('173547a7bg9459d9'[x-1999],17)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYxBCsMgFAXX9RTuotCCWsX8kN6iu7YLg0kjJFaCofb09mcz8GDmpV@eP1HV6fasi1sH72jpJIDtS6@ENC56GmJmjbRXo62zwxu0AQ/No1zQg9dZWl6/c1hGet/2sSOntB3FxEJMe2ac8ypBCIJ2ewCIEjjxXSNU@wc)